# What should I keep in mind while buying a new wifi router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I want to buy a WiFi router which can help me connect 18-20 people directly on a single router.
the real use is to get lag-free WiFi-LAN gaming b/w 20 people/computers.
So, what are the factors that I should keep in mind while buying a router?
If there is a better way of LAN gaming on WiFi then you are free to suggest.

Comment: What kind of gaming are you looking to do with 20 people over wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When buying consumer Wi-Fi routers, always buy high-end flagship models. They're the only ones where the design trade-offs valued performance over price.

For best performance and lowest latency, buy all new wireless adapters for all your client machines (bring them all up to 2-3 spatial stream 802.11ac). If a friend brings over some cheap laptop that doesn't have at least two-spatial-stream 802.11ac, his obsolete/cheap Wi-Fi card can take a disproportional amount of air time to send the same amount of traffic, ruining things for everyone. Make him use a two-spatial-stream 802.11ac USB 3.0 adapter and turn off his built-in Wi-Fi card.

Consider a so-called "tri-band" router. They have two 5GHz radios plus a 2.4GHz radio, so you can leave obsolete devices on 2.4GHz and the first 5GHz radio, and reserve the second 5GHz radio for fast 2-3 spatial stream 802.11ac gear.

As you're setting up your LAN gaming session, use a Wi-Spy DBx to check the spectrum for the cleanest channels at the time, and configure your router to use those channels.

If your so-called "LAN" gaming requires an Internet-connected LAN, then you need to make sure your Internet connection is low-latency as well. Use http://dslreports.com/speedtest to check for bufferbloat. If you have bufferbloat problems, consider running OpenWrt or DD-WRT on your router so you can enable CoDel and ECN to fix it.